# Why is there no edge in the output?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am creating a graph using **graphviz**. I am creating two subgraphs **A & B** each of which has an INIT subgraph and an error subgraph. The INIT subgraph can have multiple nodes in sequence. While in the error subgraph I want to have records (or nodes that don't have edge between them and are stacked on top of each other). I want to have an edge between the INIT subgraphs and Error Subgraph.

Here is my code:

```
digraph A {
    compound=true;
    rankdir="TB"
    graph [nodesep=1, ranksep=1];
    
    subgraph cluster_a {
        // label="A"
        style="invis"
        
        subgraph cluster_a_a {
            label="INIT-1";
            style="rect";
            node [shape="box"]
            "Load args"
        };
        
        subgraph cluster_a_b {
            label="ERROR"
            style="invis"
            node [shape="record"]
            
            struct1 [
                label="{<port1>log.error()|sys.exit(1)}"
                ]
        };
        
        "Load args" -> struct1:port1 [label="on Failure", ltail=cluster_a_a, constraint=false];
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_b {
        // label="B"
        style="invis"
        
        subgraph cluster_b_a {
            label="INIT-2";
            style="rect";
            node [shape="box"]
            "Initialize SparkSession" -> "Create MySqlConnection"
        }
        
        subgraph cluster_b_b {
            label="ERROR"
            style="invis"
            node [shape="record"]
            
            struct2 [
                label="{<port1>log.error()|sys.exit(1)}"
                ]
        }    
        
        "Create MySqlConnection" -> struct2:port1 [label="on Failure", ltail="cluster_b_a", constraint=false]
    }
    
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Why is there no edge between `INIT-1 (Load Args)` and `log.error()`?

**Additional question:** Why are the nodes in INIT-2 skewed and not centered?

Link : [Project link](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20compound%3Dtrue%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rankdir%3D%22TB%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20graph%20%5Bnodesep%3D1%2C%20ranksep%3D1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_a%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20label%3D%22A%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22invis%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_a_a%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22INIT-1%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22rect%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3D%22box%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Load%20args%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_a_b%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22ERROR%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22invis%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3D%22record%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20struct1%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7B%3Cport1%3Elog.error%28%29%7Csys.exit%281%29%7D%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Load%20args%22%20-%3E%20struct1%3Aport1%20%5Blabel%3D%22on%20Failure%22%2C%20ltail%3Dcluster_a_a%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_b%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20label%3D%22B%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22invis%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_b_a%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22INIT-2%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22rect%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3D%22box%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Initialize%20SparkSession%22%20-%3E%20%22Create%20MySqlConnection%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_b_b%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22ERROR%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22invis%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3D%22record%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20struct2%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7B%3Cport1%3Elog.error%28%29%7Csys.exit%281%29%7D%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Create%20MySqlConnection%22%20-%3E%20struct2%3Aport1%20%5Blabel%3D%22on%20Failure%22%2C%20ltail%3D%22cluster_b_a%22%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Which version of dot are you using as on http://www.webgraphviz.com/I see the edge.

Comment: I am using it on the Graphviz visual Editor. Link added in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz is producing these warnings (that you are probably not seeing):

```
Warning: flat edge between adjacent nodes one of which has a record shape - replace records with HTML-like labels
  Edge struct1 -> Load args
Error: lost Load args struct1 edge
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style rect - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style rect - ignoring
```

If you replace your **record**-style nodes with **html**-style nodes, edges should show.
As a guess, the "skewed" nodes are caused by the **on Failure** edge label.  Try using **xlabel**.